# SQL Server Supported Transaction Models

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactions, nested, distributed

I have a question about SQL server Transaction Models.
As much as I know, we have 5 models or modes of transaction in database(Flat, Distributed, Nested, Multilevel and Chained).
I wanna know which one of them exist in SQL server (any version) or in a better way, SQL have what kind of transaction model and support them?
I surfed the web but I couldnt find anything related to my question.
Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search suggests the following article [Exploring SQL Server's Distributed Transactions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190612(v=sql.105).aspx), which should give you a starting point for your actual question.

*Update*

From Technet's documentation on [Transactions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190612(v=sql.105).aspx):

- Explicit Transactions *Explicitly start a transaction.*
- Autocommit Transactions *Each individual Transact-SQL statement is committed when it
  completes.*
- Implicit Transactions *The next statement automatically
  starts a new transaction. When that transaction is completed, the
  next Transact-SQL statement starts a new transaction.*

So while the terminology is a little different, Flat, Distributed, Nested and Chained are supported. Multilevel may also be, but I'm not familiar enough with its semantics to say.

You may also be interested in [Isolation Levels in the Database Engine](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189122(v=sql.105).aspx), which in my opinion can have a much larger impact on your application's characteristics (where distributed tranactions are arguably more of a system level concern?)

Comment: This link just talking about distributed transaction model but I wanna know about all of them with some examples

Comment: @EhsanNabavi I've updated the answer with a little more analysis. Good luck.